Using html in question titles in survey.js
We are creating a form with survey.js. However, we will add a checkbox for mandatory choices regarding kvkk and we need to show some text in the title for the explanations to be seen. We also want to add capctha verification.
sample
I tried to write html content for the titles on the survey.js screen but it didn't work

SurveyJS supports formatting of labels and titles through Markdown, however it can be extended to support HTML as well. To acheive that you need to use a library like markdown-it. You will also need to handle the onTextMarkdown event of the Survey. This is documented with a working demo here.
Here's how to implement this with React:
import React from "react";
import { Model } from "survey-core";
import { Survey } from "survey-react-ui";
import "survey-core/defaultV2.min.css";
import "./index.css";
import { json } from "./json";
import markdownit from "markdown-it"; // <-- Import the 3rd party library

function SurveyComponent() {
  const survey = new Model(json);
  survey.onComplete.add((sender, options) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(sender.data, null, 3));
  });
  // Instantiate `markdown-it`
  const converter = markdownit({
    html: true, // <-- Enable HTML support
  });
  survey.onTextMarkdown.add((_, options) => {
    // Convert Markdown to HTML
    let str = converter.renderInline(options.text);
    options.html = str;
  });
  return <Survey model={survey} />;
}

export default SurveyComponent;

You can then include HTML in your titles like so:
export const json = {
  elements: [
    {
      type: "checkbox",
      name: "Question1",
      title:
        "Check the box to continue",
      choices: [
        {
          value: 1,
          text: "I agree to the <a href='https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public'>terms & conditions</a>",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  showQuestionNumbers: false,
};

Here's a full working example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/awesome-dust-6n4qf8?workspaceId=64c276ad-0dfc-48c8-9e36-39d45ffd6536
IMPORTANT: Enabling HTML support as shown here is considered unsafe. Make sure you sanitize the HTML before applying it to the text labels.
